# Make side blocks stay on the same level when scrolling down

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid

I need to have this layout:

[image]

And when you scroll down, `red` blocks should stay on the same level as `green` block:

[image]

I have tried to use grid to fix this problem:
([plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2GZ2xTAiU69f0liTNoaN?p=preview))

```
<div class="row md-padding">
  <div class="col-xs-3" style="background-color:red">
    <div>
      <h3>Red</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-5" style="margin-left:10px;margin-right:10px; background-color:green;">
    <div class="row">
      <h3 class="text-center">Green</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-3" style="background-color:red">
    <div>
      <h3>Red</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It did put red blocks where they should be, but when you scroll down, they are no longer visible.

**How can I make red blocks stay on the same level?** (as described on img2)

Comment: Do you mean to say that only green should be scrollable?

Comment: @HebleV no, I mean when you scroll, red blocks act normally before grey block is hidden, and after it is, they are `fixed`

Comment: so you mean when you scroll down grey goes upper and then red should take that place and then get fixed at that place?

Comment: Just use a `JavaScript` function that's triggered `onscroll`. If `scroll` > `grayBarHeight` then `red position fixed`. Although note i'm not sure how responsive fixed elements are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're looking for

```
position:fixed;
```

updated [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/uPjEecZ8eYi9AIzwafy5?p=preview)

Comment: It is not exactly what I need. I need it to be fixed and on top of the page when you scroll it (image 2). what you suggested, makes it fixed in the middle of the page. Scroll yourself,and you'll see.

Comment: i've updated the plunkr in my answer. check again and let me know if this is what you're going for.